# How can I add column resizing to a MooTools sortable table?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, mootools, tablesorter

I want a table [similar to this one](http://joomlicious.com/mootable/), but where the user can adjust the height of the table as well as sort it.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the good one here 
http://groups.google.com/group/flexigrid/?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

http://demos111.mootools.net/Resizable